# Hash function for sorting 100 or more integar numbers

Tags: c

I searched the problem but not satisfied, so that I want to ask a question. If I want to sort suppose 100 numbers using hash table what hash function may help me.I sorted 10 numbers(by bucketsort) through the table, of whats length was 10. Without increasing the table length how could I still imply bucket sort there.X%10 will not help me any more?. So how could I still sort my numbers.

Comment: Sorting 100 numbers - no effort at all. Use a bubble sort - it will do

Comment: How will a hash function help you perform a sort?

Comment: I don't want bubble sort here.....Ed heal? I know your advise well.

Comment: It will help me make my hash table. By using hash table I could sort numbers.@tom

Comment: Let me rephrase:  How will a hash table help you perform a sort?  A hash table provides a fast lookup by some key.  It won't help you perform a sort.

Comment: I found topics on how hash function works on float numbers in the book of "Introduction to algorithm by Cormen". That's why I guessed further.

Comment: Add clarity.  What do you want to do with the numbers after they are sorted?

Answer (score 2):

A HashTable is absolutely useless in this scenario.
A hash specifically **removes** ordering information, making it impossible to sort!

Assume that `A < B`.
When you have `hash(A)` and `hash(B)`, you cannot make ANY statement about the relationship.

Any of the following are possibly true:

- `hash(A)  < hash(B)`
- `hash(A) == hash(B)`
- `hash(A)  > hash(B)`

So you cannot use a hash function to sort.

***HashTables are not for sorting!***

Use Function [QSort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

```
int LessThan(const void* pA, const void* pB) { return *(int*)pA - *(int*)pB; }

int main()
{
    int num[100];
    // Fill in the array

    qsort(num, 100, sizeof(int), LessThan);

    // Your array is now sorted.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want qsort @abelenky

Comment: May be I can sort float numbers by hash table? If u kindly add suggestion.

Comment: I found topics on how hash function works on float numbers in the book of "Introduction to algorithm by Cormen". That's why I guessed further.

Comment: You're not listening. You are confusing totally unrelated concepts. Hash functions specifically remove any "orderedness" your inputs might have had, making sorting them impossible. If you need to sort, just sort. There are hundreds of algorithms for that--not a single one of which uses a hash function, for good reason.

Comment: Thanks. Always problem for the beginners, u know. Thanks crocker@Crocker